# Script working from powershell ISE but not from powershell

Tags: powershell, powercli, powershell-ise

I am trying to connect to vsphere using powercli and the powershell script contents are below,

```
# test.ps1
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$False
Connect-VIServer server_name -User username -Password  pass
```

If I execute the script from powershell ISE it's working fine and it will connect. But the same is not happening from powershell and getting below error

```
Connect-VIServer : 8/11/2021 4:00:32 PM Connect-VIServer                Error: Invalid server certificate. Use
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration to set the value for the InvalidCertificateAction option to Prompt if you'd like to connect
once or to add a permanent exception for this server.
Additional Information: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'x.x.x.x'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-VIServer x.x.x.x -User username -Password pass
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Connect-VIServer], ViSecurityNegotiationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_ConnectivityServiceImpl_Reconnect_CertificateError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.
   Cmdlets.Commands.ConnectVIServer
```

Comment: Try using a server FQDN not IP?

Comment: I have tried with FQDN also still same issue

Comment: Are you using a different user? Is there a reason you're setting the scope to user for `Set-PowerCLI`? Have you tried using a scope of session instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the powershell command shell in an elevated level.
run your script from an elevated powershell command shell.
shift + Right mouse click powershell icon and select run as Administrator
once this is opened run your script.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.